Pivot table in excel: get difference of two rows in original table as a value
I have a huge table that looks something like this:



Period
Retailer
Area
Section of people
Goods type
Metric 1: Quantity sold




q1
some dude
area1
1
doll
111


q2
some dude
area1
1
doll
100


q1
some dude
area1
1
ball
15


q2
some dude
area1
1
ball
800


q1
some other dude
area2
1
car
123421


q2
some other dude
area2
1
car
35



I need to make a dashboard of metric dynamics betweeen q2 and q1, where the value for each metric col is the difference between the two (which possibly we'll turn into a percentage) Also, possible filters include Retailer, Area, Section of people




doll
ball
car




Metric 1: Quantity sold
-11 (=100-111)
785 (=800-15)
-123386


Metric 2: ….






What is the best way to achieve that? I have created a PivotTable, but I fail to see how to get the values for q2-q1 correctly.

Is there a way to create a formula from the pivot table without referencing the row numbers (since the rows are not necessarily sorted in order q1 -> q2 for each respective item)?  It suggests some by default but none of them fits my purpose
Is it better to divide the original table first somehow?

Any help and sources appreciated!

What happens if there is q3 and q4? because if i understand correctly, q1 refers to quarter one and q2 refers to quarter two so what happens there after for the following quarters, what should be the logic then?

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range or from within sheet
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

Editto allow q1 and q2 to be input in other than sorted order, we add a sort to the aggregation.
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//Group by "Goods type"
// then add custom aggregation to subtract first metric value from second
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Goods type"}, {
        {"Metric 1: Quantity sold", (t)=>let 
                tbl= Table.Sort(t,{"Period", Order.Ascending})
            in 
                tbl[#"Metric 1: Quantity sold"]{1} - tbl[#"Metric 1: Quantity sold"]{0}}
        }),

//Transpose the table
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Grouped Rows"),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Demoted Headers"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers"

You can easily add in the appropriate aggregations for your other metrics. But may have to make some other changes depending on the nature of those metrics.


You can use the following formula as well. This assumes that there is no Excel Constraints as per the tags posted. That is it works Exclusively with MS365:


• Formula used in cell H9
=LET(
     _Data, GoodsTbl[#All],
     _GoodType, DROP(INDEX(_Data,,5),1),
     _QtySold, DROP(_Data,1,5),
     _Uniq, TOROW(UNIQUE(_GoodType)),
     _Labels, TOCOL(DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,5)),
     _Headers, VSTACK("Goods Type",_Labels),
     _Metric, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Labels),COLUMNS(_Uniq), LAMBDA(r,c,
              INDEX(MMULT({-1,1},FILTER(_QtySold, _GoodType=INDEX(_Uniq,c),0)),r))),
     _Output, HSTACK(_Headers, VSTACK(_Uniq, _Metric)),
     _Output)



The above formula is one single dynamic array formula, one needs to enter the range once. Also I am using Structured References aka Tables which makes easier to adjust the formula automatically when there is a change in the source.
Using LET() function helps in defining variables so as it makes easier to read and understand, as well redundant calculations are avoided thus improves the performance overall of calculations.
So _Data refers to the whole source range that is GoodsTbl[#All]
_GoodType refers to the Column E values extracted using DROP() and INDEX() function.
_QtySold refers to the metric quantities, extracted using DROP() function.
Using UNIQUE() function extracting the unique values and converting it into a single row.
_Lables refers to the headers of the range, extracted using DROP() and TAKE() and converted into a single column.
Using MAKEARRAY() function, which is a LAMBDA() helper function to perform certain calculations to return an array specified for the numbers of rows and columns. It does two primary operations one is to extract metrics qty based on the good types and then subtracts it up for two periods (q1, and q2) to return the output.
Finally, in the last step, we are using HSTACK() and VSTACK() function to layout our desired output.


NOTE: The above formula can be modified for if required. As it is not clear what should happen if there is other periods, in the OP it is stated for only two periods but shown for two metrics quantities sold which the formula takes care off. Needs confirmation for the periods.


This is a very nicely laid out answer.

@whiskeychief Sir, thanks for sharing your valuable feedback, glad to hear that from you!!
